# Question about coordinate system of a manifold

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds

Okay, So I want to make this concept clear now since I am struggling with it for a long time, let me define it first.
Let $S$ be a manifold and $\phi:S\to\Bbb{R^n}$ be a coordinate system for $S$.Then $\phi$ maps each point $p$ in $S$ to $n$ real numbers: $\phi(p)=[\xi^1(p),...,\xi^n(p)]$.These are the coordinates of the point $p$.Each $\xi^i$ may be viewed as a function $\xi^i:S\to\mathbb{R}.$

Now suppose I have a one dimensional manifold $\Bbb{S^1}=\{(x,y) \mid x^2+y^2=1\}$.Let us have an open set  $U=\{(x,y)\in \Bbb{S^1}\mid y>0\}$ now if I take a point $p\in U$ and by definition above we have to find the coordinates of $p$ .(Although in this case, we know that $p$ will be some ordered pair $(x,y).$) But I want to find it with the help of the above definition. Let a homeomorphism $\phi: U\to(-1,1)$ such that $\phi(p)=x$ ( So basically I am projecting it to the x-axis.) Now if we see the definition it says that $\phi(p)=[\xi^1,..,\xi^n]$ will be the coordinates of $p$ so here we have $\phi(p)=x=[\xi^1]$ so by this coordinates of $p$ should be $x=[\xi^1]$, But this does not seem correct to me can someone tell me where is the mistake. Thanks.

Comment: It seems like your set $U$ is just all of $\mathbb{S}^1$ ? That's not going to work, you probably want something like $U = \{(x, y) \in S^1 \mid y > 0\}$.

Comment: yes,That was a mistake,thanks.